# W3 validator CSS error : Value Error : speak none is not a speak value : none

Tags: magento2

W3 validator CSS error: Value Error: speak none is not a speak value: none - there are so many errors like that so I need to fix so help me

https://prnt.sc/uzm6pb

Comment: Please add more info.